# Laravel custom Facade strange behaviour - Facade overwriting singleton definition

Tags: php, laravel, singleton

I try to use method of Facade accessor:

> Call to undefined method App\Baselinker\BaselinkerFacade::products()

I am really confused because if I try to access Baselinker::products() from tinker console, everything works perfectly. The error is thrown when I try to access Baselinker class from controller. The only way it worked was when I tried this way:

```
app(Baselinker::class)->products()
```

Facade:

```
class Baselinker extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor(): string
    {
        return 'baselinker';
    }
}
```

BaselinkerServiceProvider:

```
public function register() : void
{
    $this->app->singleton('baselinker', function(){
         return new App\Baselinker\Baselinker(config('services.baselinker.token'));
    });
}

public function provides(): array
{
    return [App\Baselinker\Baselinker::class];
}
```

config/app.php

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Baselinker' => App\Facades\Baselinker::class,
    ...
]
```

**Edit:**
I found it:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

It kinda works, but I have to call it like this:

```
app('baselinker')->products()
```

It looks like the facade is overwriting singleton definition and not passing constructor argument:

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  string $token ]] > > in class App\Baselinker\Baselinker

Comment: I noticed BaselinkerServiceProvider is not called at all, so the singleton is not registered. I have no idea why... I registered singleton directly in /bootstrap/app.php and it worked.

Comment: Did you ad the `BaselinkerServiceProvider`  to the `'providers'` array in `config/app.php`?

Comment: Yes, of course. I can register it in AppServiceProvider and it works, but in the BaselinkerServiceProvider it does not.

Comment: I had to clear cache, please look at my edit. But the problem is I still can't to this - Baselinker::products()

Comment: I'm not talking about `AppServiceProvider` at all. I'm talking about the `providers` array in the `config/app.php` file.